# error compiling the opencv framework

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors

I'm trying to start learning OpenCV but I can`t even create the framework.
I'm using this command like the instructions said

```
python opencv/ios/build_framework.py ios
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> ** BUILD FAILED **

```
The following build commands failed:
Libtool /Users/myName/Documents/Apps/Frameworks/ios2/build/iPhoneSimulator-i386/modules/world/UninstalledProducts/libopencv_world.a normal i386
(1 failure)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "opencv/ios/build_framework.py", line 129, in <module>
build_framework(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "..")), os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]))
File "opencv/ios/build_framework.py", line 121, in build_framework
put_framework_together(srcroot, dstroot)
File "opencv/ios/build_framework.py", line 89, in put_framework_together
shutil.copytree(tdir0 + "/install/include/opencv2", dstdir + "/Headers")
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 168, in copytree
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../build/iPhoneOS-armv7/install/include/opencv2'
```

I don't know what to do! Please help

Comment: i get exactly the same

Comment: it works if you revert back to an earlier version of opencv, for me it worked with: git checkout 2.4.4

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$ git checkout 2.4.3 # or 2.4.4 or 2.4.3.1 or 2.4.3.2`

...somewhere in your opencv checkout before you run

`$ python ./build_framework.py <SOME_DIR_OUTSIDE_OF_OPENCV_SOURCE_TREE>`

Comment: I'd like to get it building with the latest version (2.4.5)